# Is there a way to assign a formula array to a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to lookup a value in a table called `Shop` and save it to the variable called `colorVar`. I tried two ways to set the `colorVar` (shown below), the first assigns the formula as string and the second one gives syntax error.

```
Dim colorVar as Variant

Set colorVar = "=Index(Shop[Threshold], Match(1, (RC[-5] = Shop[Name])*(R[-2]C = Shop[Region]), 0))"

'Set colorVar = Index(Shop[Threshold], Match(1, (RC[-5] = Shop[Name])*(R[-2]C = Shop[Region]), 0))

If (colorVar = False) Then
   Cell(12,12).Interior.Color = vbRed
End If
```

I have a workaround, i.e., saving the value to a cell that has the `FormulaArray` and then assigning it the `colorVar` and then clearing that cell as shown below. But wanted to know if there is something better.

```
Dim colorVar as Variant

Cell(12,12).FormulaArray = "=Index(Shop[Threshold], Match(1, (RC[-5] = Shop[Name])*(R[-2]C = Shop[Region]), 0))"
Set colorVar = Cell(12,12).Value
Cell(12,12).Clear

If (colorVar = False) Then
   Cell(12,12).Interior.Color = vbRed
End If
```

Comment: The `Set` keyword is only used for objects e.g. ranges, worksheets, workbooks... etc. Just remove it. What is the expected result? Your formula is written to a single cell and returns a single result so why aren't you using `.Formula2` instead of `.FormulaArray`? What exactly is `Cell(12, 12)`? Is it `L12` or something else? Also, clarify where the cell and the table are located (worksheet, workbook) so we can give a more accurate answer.

Comment: `Evaluate`, or `Worksheet.Evaluate` only work with A1-style references. If the table is on `Sheet1` and the cells are on `Sheet2`, you could do something like this: `colorVar = Sheet1.Evaluate("INDEX(Shop[Threshold],Match(1,(Shop[Name]=Sheet2!G12)*(Shop[Region]=Sheet2!L10),0))")`. If you can clarify what was asked, I could write more flexible version.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Although, I modified your answer to suit my need. As I'm looping over columns (i) from 12 to n (n is the last column - 22), I need that cell referencing. So, I evaluate the cell address, ```cellAddress = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("Address(12," & i & ")")``` and then evaluate ```colorVar``` ```colorVar = Sheet1.Evaluate("INDEX(Shop[Threshold],Match(1,(Shop[Name]=" & cellAddress & ")*(Shop[Region]=Sheet2!L10),0))")```